# vue-router transition suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am working on my personal website currently. For the frontend I am using Vue.js with vue-router. Until today the transition worked fine, you can see here: https://imanuel.ulbricht.codes/ (you need to scroll down or use the arrow key down). But after some changes that I cannot really find it stopped working.

This is how it "works" now: https://imanuel-not-working.ulbricht.codes/. I really have no idea what I changed, that might affect this change in behavior, maybe someone has an idea.

Side note: The published code has sourcemaps enabled so you should see the complete Vue.js source code.

Another point, the code should animate the page transition, that doesn't happen currently. After 2h searching I couldn't find the root of the problem, if anyone could give me a hint what code might be the cause I will add it to the question.

This is the code, that might cause the issue:

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="ulbricht-app" id="app" @wheel="navigateWheel" @keyup.down="navigateNext" @keyup.up="navigatePrevious">
        <ribbon v-if="!$route.meta.isHelloWorld"/>
        <transition>
            <div class="ulbricht-slice__top" :class="{ 'ulbricht-slice__hello-world': $route.meta.isHelloWorld }"></div>
        </transition>
        <NavIndicator v-if="!$route.meta.isHelloWorld"/>
        <transition name="ulbricht-router__fade" mode="out-in">
            <router-view/>
        </transition>
        <transition>
            <div class="ulbricht-slice__bottom" v-if="!$route.meta.isHelloWorld"></div>
        </transition>
    </div>
</template>

<script>    
    export default {
        components: {
            NavIndicator,
            Ribbon
        },
        name: 'App',
        mounted() {
            window.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
                if (event.key === 'ArrowUp') {
                    this.navigatePrevious();
                } else if (event.key === 'ArrowDown') {
                    this.navigateNext();
                }
            });
        },
        methods: {
            navigateWheel($event) {
                if ($event.deltaY > 0) {
                    this.navigateNext();
                } else {
                    this.navigatePrevious();
                }
            },
            navigateNext() {
                if (this.$route.meta.next) {
                    this.$router.push(this.$route.meta.next);
                }
            },
            navigatePrevious() {
                if (this.$route.meta.previous) {
                    this.$router.push(this.$route.meta.previous);
                }
            }
        }
    };
</script>

<style lang="scss">    
    .ulbricht-app {    
        .ulbricht-slice__top {
            background: var(--primary);
            position: absolute;
            width: 200%;
            z-index: 0;
            transition: transform 0.4s, height 0.4s;
            height: 250px;
            transform: skewY(-3deg);
            left: 0;
            top: -210px;

            &.ulbricht-slice__hello-world {
                transition: transform 0.4s, height 0.2s;
                top: -25px;
                height: 120%;
                transform: skewY(15deg);
            }
        }

        .ulbricht-router__fade-enter-active {
            span,
            p,
            h1,
            img {
                transition: opacity 0.3s;
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }

        .ulbricht-router__fade-leave-active {
            span,
            p,
            h1,
            img {
                transition: opacity 0.3s;
                opacity: 0;
            }
        }
    }
</style>
```

And one of the components, they basically all look the same just the content varies.

```
<template>
    <div class="ulbricht-app ulbricht-app__hello">
        <img class="ulbricht-hello__background" src="../assets/background.png" alt="">
        <div class="ulbricht-hello__content">
            <h1 class="ulbricht-hello__header">
                Hello World, I am Imanuel
            </h1>
            <p class="ulbricht-hello__text">
                What I do is dead simple, I write software, design websites and landscapes,<br/>
                let me show you what I am capable of
            </p>
            <router-link class="ulbricht-chevron" :to="$route.meta.next">
                <span class="ulbricht-chevron__button"></span>
            </router-link>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'HelloWorld'
    };
</script>
```

And the NavIndicator component, I think after adding this component it stopped working, but I am not sure.

```
<template>
    <div class="ulbricht-sidenav">
        <router-link :to="$route.meta.previous || ''" class="ulbricht-sidenav__chevron is--up"
                     :class="{'is--disabled': !$route.meta.previous}"></router-link>
        <router-link :to="nav" class="ulbricht-sidenav__dot" :class="{'is--active': $route.name === nav.name}"
                     :title="nav.meta.title" v-for="nav in navs"></router-link>
        <router-link :to="$route.meta.next || ''" class="ulbricht-sidenav__chevron is--down"
                     :class="{'is--disabled': !$route.meta.next}"></router-link>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Routes from "../router/Routes";

    export default {
        name: "NavIndicator",
        computed: {
            navs() {
                return Routes;
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss">
    .ulbricht-sidenav {
        position: fixed;
        right: 1em;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        z-index: 9999;
    }

    .ulbricht-sidenav__chevron {
        &::before {
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 0.25em 0.25em 0 0;
            content: '';
            display: inline-block;
            height: 0.45em;
            left: 0.15em;
            position: relative;
            vertical-align: top;
            width: 0.45em;
            border-color: var(--primary);
            margin-right: 0.3em;
        }

        &.is--disabled {
            &::before {
                border-color: var(--primary-grey);
            }
        }

        &.is--up {
            &::before {
                transform: rotate(-45deg);
                top: 0.5em;
            }
        }

        &.is--down {
            &::before {
                top: 0;
                transform: rotate(135deg);
            }
        }
    }

    .ulbricht-sidenav__dot {
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 1em;
        height: 1em;
        border: 0.2em solid var(--primary-opaque-0\.5);
        margin-top: 0.25em;
        margin-bottom: 0.25em;
        transition: border 0.3s, background 0.3s;

        &.is--active {
            background: var(--primary);
        }

        &:hover {
            border: 0.2em solid var(--primary-opaque-0\.7);
            background: var(--primary);
        }
    }
</style>
```

Removing this component, however, didn't have an effect.

As addition, here is the Github Link, so you can investigate all of the source code if I might have forgotten something, that might be relevant.

https://github.com/DerKnerd/imanuel.ulbricht.codes/tree/98272361549617191bb6d6f5d88ad88c94cbdcfe

Comment: You should post the relevant source with the question.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help _("why isn't this code working?")_ must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: Ok, the problem is, I have no idea what part of the code is the root of the problem. The desired behavior is fairly simple, it should animate. Should I then post the whole code here? I tried to tackle it down for about 2h and have no clue where the problem comes from.

Comment: The thing is, Stack Overflow is not a personal debugging service. Questions should be useful for others as well and without a clear and complete description, it doesn't help anybody.

Comment: In addition, the static assets are compiled (minimized, etc.) on your site, so we can't really explore the sources.

Comment: I added a more detailed description of the desired behavior and what it does not currently. I will post code that might cause it in about 15 minutes, but it might be a lot of code...

Comment: Yes you can, they contain source maps like I pointed out.

Comment: Try to remove anything that is not related to the question from the code (like presentation html, text, comments, etc.) Also keep in mind that 2 hours is nothing in development.

Comment: I know, I work in development, but for that tiny of a problem it seems pretty much time.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter I added code

Comment: @EmileBergeron I added the code

Comment: If you have this under source control, look at commit differences from around the time you had it working compared to when you think it stopped. Also note if you updated dependencies at any time, as sometimes breaking changes happen.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter that is the problem, I could reproduce the state that worked yesterday.

Comment: Well one thing I'm seeing immediately is there is a `<!-- -->` between `<div class="ulbricht-slice__top ulbricht-slice__hello-world"></div>` and  `<div class="ulbricht-app ulbricht-app__hello">` on the copy of your site that is not working. Something is being rendered/removed there.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter I added the part that is removed or rendered. It is the ribbon displaying *Find me on Behance*

Comment: @DigitalDrifter, you are my hero. I moved it down and it just worked. Do you know what the effect is? If you create the comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `<!-- -->` comment between

```
<div class="ulbricht-slice__top ulbricht-slice__hello-world"></div>
```

and

```
<div class="ulbricht-app ulbricht-app__hello">
```

on the copy of your site that is not working. Something is being rendered/removed there.

It may be causing a CSS selector to be applied incorrectly.